# managing the same several select inputs on one page with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the case is:

We're loading about 20 requests(entities) items on page load, and then 20 more on scrolling down, i.e. infinite scroll.

Each request has select dropdown with statuses, and another select with managers, so user can select manager and status and update the request via ajax. When page is refreshed, the updated request has status and manager dropdowns selected with appropriate values.

angular provides ngOptions solution for populating selects, but I have no idea how to organize ngModel for all these selects on this page.

```
<div class="request" ng-repeat="request in page.requests">
{{request.created}}
{{request.title}} 
//etc..
//here we have selects

<select class="managersSelect">
                <option value="">choose manager</option>
                <option 
                    ng-repeat="manager in page.managers" 
                    ng-selected="request.manager_id == manager.id"
                    value="{{manager.id}}">{{manager.name}}
                </option>
            </select>

//and second one

<select class="statusesSelect">
            <option
                ng-repeat="status in page.statuses"
                ng-selected="request.status == status.id"
                value="{{status.id}}">{{status.title}}
            </option>
            </select>
</div>
```

Currently I use a combination of ng-repeat and ng-selected, and it solves the problem, but how to organize ng-model for implementing recommended ng-options way?

Comment: It's better with some code you know.

Comment: sure, I've edited the question, mpm.

Comment: what was your final verdict on this?

Comment: The solution above, for my case